# Okta as Identity broker for several External IDPs

Tags: single-sign-on, integration, okta, idp

I am looking for detailed architecture to integrate at least four external IDPs to Okta that will provide users access to various apps (over 30). Can anyone please point me to similar use case architectures of integration? I intend to use OKTA as an Identity Broker for all these various Identity providers. I want to integrate all the various identity providers and Connect OKTA for SSO such that each of the various Identity providers, can pass through OKTA to grant permissions and access to my various business and technical apps. Currently, I manually add users to groups in Okta but I want to achieve some level of automation for this as much as practically possible. If there is any link with detailed architecture and steps, I would appreciate it

I have looked at Okta"s documentation to see if this can be done